# Heatmap with geom_tile how to divide and reorder based on another factor without using facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, factors

I have 100 samples, that I'm testing with 9 different tests, from several different groups.
I want to make a heatmap with the samples on the X axis and the tests on the Y axis.

Then I want to group the samples according to the group factor... and use a "custom" order (for e.g. in the following example
`c("c","b","a").`)

It would be easy to do with facets, but I plan later to make it circular (using coord_polar) so I need to keep them all together.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~sample, ~test, ~group, ~result,
  1, "alpha", "a", 1,
  1, "beta", "a", 1,
  1, "gamma", "a", 1,
  2, "alpha", "a", 0,
  2, "beta", "a", 1,
  2, "gamma", "b", 0,
  3, "alpha", "b", 0,
  3, "beta", "b", 1,
  3, "gamma", "b", 0,
  4, "alpha", "a", 1,
  4, "beta", "a", 1,
  4, "gamma", "a", 0,
  5, "alpha", "b", 0,
  5, "beta", "b", 0,
  5, "gamma", "b", 1,
  6, "alpha", "c", 0,
  6, "beta", "c", 0,
  6, "gamma", "c", 0,
)

df %>%
  mutate(across(c(sample, test, group), as.factor)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(sample, test, fill=result, color=group))+
    geom_tile()+
    theme_void()+
    coord_polar()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue is with your data, try changing your dummy data in the map function and the mean to be of 1 (as an example)

`value = unlist(map(c(10000, 10000, 10000), ~ rnorm(3, mean = 1)))`

```r
set.seed(1)
# create dummy data
df <- expand_grid(
  color = c("red", "green", "blue"),
  temperature = c("cold", "neutral", "hot")
) %>% mutate(
  value = unlist(map(c(10000, 10000, 10000), ~ rnorm(3, mean = 1)))
)
knitr::kable(df)

# plot with manual breaks
df %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_tile(aes(color, temperature, fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(#values = c(1, 0, -1) , 
                       colours= rev(c("blue","white", "red"))) +
  ggtitle('Manual values')
```

[image]